tmux-256color corrupt data found in convert_strings
I've been using a custom terminfo entry for tmux since about 2020. It reads
# A tmux-256color based TERMINFO that adds the escape sequences for italic.
#
# Install:
#
#   tic tmux-256color.terminfo
#
# Usage:
#
#   export TERM=tmux-256color
#
tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors and italic,
        use=screen-256color,
        sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
        smso=\E[7m, rmso=\E[27m,

Today I compiled it for what is probably the first time in a while with tic -x …. Now when I start a shell in tmux, I get (twice) the error message
"/Users/<me>/.terminfo/74/tmux-256color": corrupt data found in convert_strings

which I traced to this patch (aka bug, report, release)…
…but everything seems to be working.
I have an open shell from before the change; diffing the old infocmp -x against one from a new shell shows (with some context)
*** /tmp/a  2024-10-09 18:26:49.000000000 -0400
--- /tmp/b  2024-10-09 18:26:53.000000000 -0400
***************
*** 1,7 ****
  #       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /Users/<me>/.terminfo/74/tmux-256color
  tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors and italic,
!         am, km, mir, msgr, xenl,
          colors#256, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, ncv#3, pairs#32767,
          acsc=++\,\,--..00``aaffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
          bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
          clear=\E[H\E[J, cnorm=\E[34h\E[?25h, cr=^M,
--- 1,7 ----
  #       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /Users/<me>/.terminfo/74/tmux-256color
  tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors and italic,
!         OTbs, OTpt, am, km, mir, msgr, xenl, , ,
          colors#256, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, ncv#3, pairs#32767,
          acsc=++\,\,--..00``aaffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
          bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
          clear=\E[H\E[J, cnorm=\E[34h\E[?25h, cr=^M,

I have no idea what OTbs, OTpt, is, and the extra commas are odd.
Now, piping the bad infocmp -x into xxd shows that the commas have some odd bytes:
00000070: 7273 2061 6e64 2069 7461 6c69 632c 0a09  rs and italic,..
00000080: 4f54 6273 2c20 4f54 7074 2c20 616d 2c20  OTbs, OTpt, am,
00000090: 6b6d 2c20 6d69 722c 206d 7367 722c 2078  km, mir, msgr, x
000000a0: 656e 6c2c 201b 2842 2c20 2c0a 0963 6f6c  enl, .(B, ,..col

In particular, the  .(B, , is 201b 2842 2c20 2c…. On a working machine (newer macOS), infocmp -x shows …, xenl, AX, G0,.
The only other terminfo entry for tmux-256color I have on this system is from a brew-installed ncurses, version 6.5, and file says it's a 32-bit entry. My infocmp can't read it, and copying it to ~/.terminfo/… makes other programs (like Vim) fail to understand the terminal information, too.
My screen-256color entry is based on /usr/share/terminfo/73/screen-256color (comment "GNU Screen with 256 colors"), and it also shows both the odd bytes and the odd OTbs, OTpt, in infocmp -x output in both old and new shells. I haven't touched this file to my knowledge.
Oddly, changing the set -g default-terminal line to screen-256color and then starting a new server with tmux -L test new shows no errors. Yet infocmp -x shows the odd bytes and OTbs, OTpt, still.
Digging further, the Homebrew formula contains a comment about an issue with the default TERM and tools that link to system ncurses, and the conditional compilation suggests upgrading to Sonoma (macOS 14) might help?
My terminal emulator is Alacritty 0.13.2, and I am currently running tmux 3.4. The OS is macOS 12.7.2.
TL;DR
What's gone wrong, and how do I fix it?

If I'm missing any information, please let me know. This has really derailed a completely unrelated experiment :)

If you're using the bundled tic on MacOS, that predates other fixes which might explain the origin of this problem.  Time's short this week, but bug-ncurses mailing list is the proper place to discuss bugs).

@ThomasDickey If I get time I’ll post there. On a working machine, compiling with the ncurses-installed tic (to a temp dir to avoid breaking the working setup) produced a (macOS-infocmp-unreadable) 32-bit terminfo entry according to file. So I don’t think using that is going to be a solution :/

(ncurses-infocmp could read it, but that doesn’t help all my programs which presumably use the system versions)

There actually are several questions.  I'll summarize:

MacOS provides ncurses 5.7 (more than fifteen years old: see FAQ).
The older tic doesn't handle forward references in the extended capabilities.
That wasn't noticed for a long time because most of the entries using extended capabilities used existing (backward) references in the "use=" clauses.
The problem with tic was fixed in ncurses 6.2.
Apple later used the terminal database from ncurses 6.4, compounding the problem with the older tic.  I opened an issue, which after a year has gotten no response.
MacPorts and brew provide workable releases of ncurses (I get useful feedback from the former, none at all from the latter: ymmv).
ncurses 6.1 provides two formats for compiled terminfo.  The "32-bit terminfo" is a version which the older ncurses ignores.  But ncurses can compile terminal descriptions to use the older format if it is configured for ABI 5.  That is one of the configure options.
MacPorts and brew are compiled to use the default configuration (ABI 6). I suspect that the only way you would get a usable ABI 5 ncurses would be to configure and compile it yourself.  But doing that would let you rebuild the terminal database under /usr/share (not generally recommended of course).


Am I reading it right if I summarize by saying: my computer's ncurses is still 5.7 (seems confirmed by infocmp -V), which is expecting the old (non-32-bit) compiled format; the existing DB is from 6.4, and has some issues being read with the 5.7 programs? I want to make sure that I understand your proposed solution is to build a recent ncurses with 5.7-ABI compiled terminfo compatiblity, and then use that to rebuild my terminfo DB?

I've also added a few Homebrew issue links to the OP that I'm now digging into…

The homebrew issue refers to the absence of the terminal description rather than the fact that ncurses 5.7 won't work well with the later terminal databases.  Most of the bug-reporting issues with the content get the facts awry and propose workarounds that aggravate or prolong the problem :-)

Fair enough! It does seem that Sonoma updated the curses toolkit, so I may try to update today.

Bummer—my hardware doesn't support Sonoma, and while something like OpenCore sounds like a cool project, I really don't have the time to get that far into the weeds

I have Sonoma on one of my machines.  It says "6.0.20150808", which is still too old to address the database corruption as well as other more often reported problems.  Packagers used to read release notes, but that's not been the case for quite a while.

There are still problems with this approach, and I cannot recommend it except as a temporary measure. To be continued…

On the system in question, following this gist linked from Thomas Dickey's FAQ via a GitHub issue on tmux, things work again. The recipe is essentially
curl -LO https://invisible-island.net/datafiles/current/terminfo.src.gz &&
  gunzip terminfo.src.gz &&
  tic -xe tmux-256color terminfo.src &&
  rm terminfo.src

I can't actually recommend this; for other profiles, this is likely to break. And it might be broken for me, but I haven't noticed it yet. It did unblock me for now, though.

But if you use the MacOS ncurses 5.7 tic to do this, some of the entries will be corrupt.

I'd noticed the gist before - but it isn't close to accurate, and so far not worth mentioning on the FAQ.  Glancing at my test results, as much as a third of the database will show some differences doing this. The place to discuss that is on the mailing list.

@ThomasDickey that's good to know; so far, the tmux-256color entry I've extracted is working. But that could be happenstance :/

In my tests, I checked all ~27000 entries.  More than 9 thousand had differences.  You might see differences if you look closely.

Hm. I've experience some bugs indeed. First I had issues scrolling git diff output in less, though that seems to have gone away? Now, htop in tmux doesn't have colors (and probably other things are missing), though it works outside tmux. To be continued…

TL;DR: Upgrade to Sonoma if you can
Since my hardware is stuck pre-Sonoma, I can't use the new curses macOS ships with (2, 3). According to the curses maintainer, it's still not new enough to reliably fix the problem, though.
Instead, I can use yet another hack. See this benknoble/Dotfiles commit and associated warnings (5):

term: fix tmux, alacritty info
See also d0902a8 (switch from plink to zuo, 2024-10-18): after that
switch led to 1, there have continued to be problems (such as htop not
showing colors because the pairs attribute was interpreted as 0).
While upgrading to macOS Sonoma or beyond should come with new curses
that makes things work again (2, 3), at the moment my current
hardware is stuck on Monterey (and I don't relish trying OpenCore Legacy
Patcher 4 right now).
Instead, try yet another hack 3: decompile the tmux-256color entry
with a modern curses, patch it, and recompile with the system curses.
This appears to be completely working for tmux-256color, though does
require the interesting workaround of using TERMINFO_DIRS (see man infocmp
and compare with man $(brew --prefix ncurses)/share/man/man1/infocmp.1m).
The post 3 also explains most of the details, but comes with another
warning 5.
Finally, I noticed that somewhere in the process my alacritty terminfo
had broken: infocmp -x produces similarly odd byte sequence 6 that
turns on strikethrough (part of a | xxd dump):
000000a0: 206e 7063 2c20 7865 6e6c 2c20 1b5b 396d   npc, xenl, .[9m

The primary effect seems to be that italics were disabled. I can't find
a way to compile the GitHub-provided entry that doesn't have this bug,
but I can fix the italic sequences in Vim.

